# Reshaping Numpy Array from (3, 2, 3) to (3, 3, 2)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have the follow 3d numpy array in shape (3, 2, 3).

```
[
 [[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]]

 [[ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]
             ]
```

However, I need to reshape into (3, 3, 2) in the follow order:

```
[
 [[ 0  3]
  [ 6  9]
  [12 15]]

 [[ 1  4]
  [ 7 10]
  [13 16]]

 [[ 2  5]
  [ 8 11]
  [14 17]]
          ]
```

I am currently using Jupyter with a lot of trial and error.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: @Divakar That's it! Thank you. I'll have to look more into the transpose arguments.

Comment: So how exactly does selecting the axes work when given 2, 0, 1 as parameters?

Comment: I'm trying to understand since my real data has shape (3400, 7, 100) that I need to transform into (100, 3400, 7) with similar ordering as this toy example.

Comment: @5ive Would be hard to explain everything. Basically, the second axis(2) is the new first axis, zeroth axis the new second axis and so on. The documentation on it should be the best material for it.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you! I mean exactly how the axes are defined for numpy. I found [this glossary](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html) to be helpful should anyone need to know how these axes are defined.

_Axes are defined for arrays with more than one dimension. A 2-dimensional array has two corresponding axes: the first running vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and the second running horizontally across columns (axis 1).

Many operation can take place along one of these axes. For example, we can sum each row of an array, in which case we operate along columns, or axis 1_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define the original array, you can use :

```
np.arange(18).reshape(3,2,3)
```

As mentioned by @Divakar in the comments, you can use :

```
np.arange(18).reshape(3,2,3).transpose(2,0,1)
```

to get the desired result.

From `np.transpose` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html):

> axes: By default, reverse the dimensions, otherwise permute the axes
>   according to the values given.

`2,0,1` is the permutation needed to go from `(3,2,3)` shape to `(3,3,2)`. It would also convert a `(3400, 7, 100)` shape into `(100, 3400, 7)`.

Another method would be to use [`np.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) (another hint from @Divakar):

```
np.rollaxis(np.arange(18).reshape(3,2,3),2)
```

Comment: Or `rollaxis` : `np.rollaxis(a,2,0)`. Or simply : `np.rollaxis(a,2)`.

Comment: @Divakar: Impressive. Feel free to write an answer, I'd delete mine.

Comment: I would encourage you to add that too in your post.

Comment: Thank you @EricDuminil and @Divakar!

Comment: @EricDuminil So I assume this method should also work when reshaping from arbitrary shapes such as (3400, 7, 100)  into (100, 3400, 7) with similar ordering as this toy example?

Comment: @5ive: Yes, the same permutation applies.